# Logging with istio

Tags: logging, kubernetes, trace, istio

I have a project with microservices in kubernetes connected though rest swagger clients.
I want to make logging of all request and response payloads.
So that for each request there is an id and information about where it came from with full payload. And for each service to service call as well.

Is it possible to do that with Istio? 
There is distributed tracing tools: zipkin, jaeger. But looks like they log only time.

Or better to handle it each app code internally?

Answer (score 2):

By default, you don't have a logging system on Istio. I mean, besides the native logging of Kubernetes.

Zipkin and Jaeger are tracing systems, meaning for latency, not for logging.

You can definitely get this info through Istio components, but you will have to set it up first. I found [this](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/logs/) articles; in Istio website about how to collect logs. I would say `Fluentd` + `Elasticsearch` would give you something as powerful as you need. Unfortunately I don't have any examples.